# Using unique class objects multi thread pool C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

This is a follow up question to [Use ThreadPool in C# within a loop and wait for all threads to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197591/use-threadpool-in-c-sharp-within-a-loop-and-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish/61197687#61197687) and [Save the content of several csv files into a searchable array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554595/save-the-content-of-several-csv-files-into-a-searchable-array-c-sharp/60554810#60554810)

I have a code that looks like this:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ThreadPooling
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                var FolderNames= new List<(string name)>()
                {
                  "folder1",
                  "folder2"
                }

                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var folder in FolderNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Staring process" + folder.name + "...");
                    var task = Task.Run(() => Job(folder.name));
                    tasks.Add(task);
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine("All calculations done.");
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit the program...");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

            public class Job()
            {
               public Job(folder)
               {
                   CsvFile File = new CsvFile();
                   File.OpenCsvFiles(folder); //opens all csv files within the folder
               }
            }

    public class CsvFile
    {
        string folder;

        static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>> _dictionary =
                                new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>>();

        public void OpenCsvFiles(string folder) //opens all the csv files in the output folder and saves their's content to a Dictionary
        {
            this.folder = folder;

            foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.csv")) // fileName is the file name WITH its full path
            {
                try
                {
                    string[][] m_Data = File
                    .ReadLines(path)
                    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    //.Skip(1) //skipping the headers
                    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                    .ToArray();

                    PopulateDictionary(Path.GetFileName(path), m_Data); //fills the Dictionary with each file
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in OpenCsvFiles (" + path + ") : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        static void PopulateDictionary(string filename, string[][] data)
        {
            _dictionary.Add(filename, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>());

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                _dictionary[filename].Add(i, new Dictionary<int, string>());

                for (int j = 0; j < data[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    _dictionary[filename][i].Add(j, data[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }



        }
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to loop a list of folders, open all .csv files in each of the folders and save the values to a dictionary in `CsvFile` accessible to each `Process` that is run parallel. However, I run into the problem that C#, unlike C++, does not seem to create separate class objects of `CsvFile` within `Process`. That is, if I run into a file with the same file name in folder1 and folder2, say file Alpha.csv, I get an error that the code tires to add the same key, Alpha, twice to the dictionary.

But I want the dictionaries in `CsvFile` to be created and used separately with in each class object of `Process`, not one `CsvFile` object to be created and then used by all `Process` classes parallel. Is this possible?

Comment: Change your name of the 'process' class, there's already one in .net and this is very confusing. Call it a job or whatever

Comment: Okay, I have done it now.

Comment: At least your `_dictionary` must be a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: do a general readup on 'atomicity' and 'thread safety' when going multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with:

```
 static Dictionary
```

When I removed static it worked. Otherwise, `_dictionary` will be the same all during all runs.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in .net reference types (`object` class, also `string` for example) are passed as reference, and value types (`int`, `float`, `char` etc) are passed as value.

If you want seperate objects you need to create a new object with the `new` operator. You can therefore do something like this:

```
var obj1 = new SomeClassIDefined(someInt, someString, someClass);
var obj2 = new SomeClassIDefined(obj.someInt, obj.someString, obj.someClass);
```

Additionally there's cloning, which basically is the same process above, but you move this to a seperate function instead. `object` already has a protected method you could use to clone an object:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Person ShallowCopy()
    {
       return (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public Person DeepCopy()
    {
       Person other = (Person) this.MemberwiseClone();
       other.IdInfo = new IdInfo(IdInfo.IdNumber);
       other.Name = String.Copy(Name);
       return other;
    }
}
```

Be sure to carefully read though the docs of cloning! In short, you can clone items deep or shallow. Shallow means that you return a new object with all value types copied over, but all references to reference types stay intact. A deep copy means you copy value types, but also copy each reference type to a new object.

Comment: I do have the line `CsvFile File = new CsvFile();` in my code above. But that does not seem to be enough?

Comment: `CsvFile File = new CsvFile();` i see that, but you're not really doing anything with the File variable

Comment: Correct, I made an error in the code put here. But it still does not work.